# Why the redux state is undefined while I updating the another redux state?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I tried to change the language based on the `languageSelectedIndex` in redux state, and I give the redux action in select location screen for choose the location and I planed to store that value into redux location state but the other state in the redux are going undefined.

**App.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import HomeScreen from './android/app/src/HomeScreen/HomeScreen';
import SelectLocation from './android/app/src/SelectLocation/SelectLocation';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux'

let initialState={
  languageSelectedIndex:0,
  name:'',
  email:'',
  phone:'',
  address:'',
  location:1,
  living:1,
  transport:0,
  bedroom:'',
  bathroom:'',
  storageroom:'',
  require_hours:0,
  require_days:0,
  week_or_month:0,
  weekdays:[],
  service_start: '',
  voucher:'',
  need_help:''
}

const reducer = (state =initialState , action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'LANG_INDEX-CHANGER':
        return {languageSelectedIndex:action.key}

      case 'LOCATION_CHANGER':
        return{location:action.location}

    default:
      return state
  }
}
const store=createStore(reducer)

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {

   HomeScreen:HomeScreen,
   SelectLocation:SelectLocation,
   DwellmingScreen:DwellmingScreen,
   TransportLine:TransportLine,
   SelectingRoomScreen:SelectingRoomScreen,
   SelectingHourScreen:SelectingHourScreen,
   SelectingDateScreen:SelectingDateScreen,
   FinalScreen:FinalScreen,
  personalInfoScreen:personalInfoScreen,    
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
    headerLayoutPreset: 'center',


  }
);


const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
      <AppContainer />
      </Provider>
    );

  }
}
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text,StyleSheet,Image,TouchableWithoutFeedback,TouchableOpacity,ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {Header,Body,Title}from 'native-base';
import uncheck from '../assets/roundUncheck.png';
import checked from '../assets/checkedRadioButton.png';
import WelcomeScreen from '../WelcomeScreen/WelcomeScreen';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class chooseLanguageScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

      return {
        header:null
      };
    };


    state={
      language:[],
      intialLanguage:0,
      uncheckRadioImage:uncheck,
      checkedRadioButton:checked,
      heading:'',
      next:'',
      dataFetched:0,

    };




    componentWillMount(){

      this.urlFinder(this.props.languageSelectedIndex)
      console.warn('mounted')
    }



    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
      console.warn('component DU homescreen')
      if(this.props.languageSelectedIndex!==prevProps.languageSelectedIndex)
      {
       this.urlFinder(this.props.languageSelectedIndex)
      }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps,nextState)
    {
      console.warn('im WU home')
      if(this.props.languageSelectedIndex!==nextProps.languageSelectedIndex)
      {
        this.urlFinder(this.props.languageSelectedIndex)
      }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(){
      this.urlFinder(this.props.languageSelectedIndex)
    }
    urlFinder(value){
        this.setState({
          dataFetched:0
        })
        let checkedValue=value;
      if(checkedValue==0){
        fetch('url', {
          method: 'GET'
          //Request Type 
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      //If response is in json then in success
      .then((responseJson) => {
          //Success 

          this.setState({
            heading:responseJson.heading,
            next: responseJson.next,
            language:responseJson.languages,
            dataFetched:1
          });
      })
      //If response is not in json then in error
      .catch((error) => {
          //Error 
          console.error(error);
      });
      }
     else if(checkedValue==1){
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET'
        //Request Type 
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    //If response is in json then in success
    .then((responseJson) => {
        //Success 

        this.setState({
          heading:responseJson.heading,
          next: responseJson.next,
          language:responseJson.languages,
          dataFetched:1
        });
    })
    //If response is not in json then in error
    .catch((error) => {
        //Error 
        console.error(error);
    });
      }
      else if(checkedValue==2){
        fetch(url, {
          method: 'GET'
          //Request Type 
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      //If response is in json then in success
      .then((responseJson) => {
          //Success 

          this.setState({
            heading:responseJson.heading,
            next: responseJson.next,
            language:responseJson.languages,
            dataFetched:1
          });
      })
      //If response is not in json then in error
      .catch((error) => {
          //Error 
          console.error(error);
      });
      }
    }





    render() {

      return (

        <View style={style.newStyle}>


        <WelcomeScreen/>

                <Header style={{ backgroundColor:'#862a2a',width:'100%', height:80,}}>      
                     <Body style={{alignItems:'center',marginHorizontal:100}}>
                          <Title style={{width:200,marginBottom:10}}>WECLEAN4YOU</Title>
                     </Body> 

                </Header>


                <View style={{width:'100%',height:'3%',backgroundColor:'#af4141',flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <View style={{width:'6%',height:'100%',backgroundColor:'orange'}}/> 
                <View style={{marginLeft:-5,width:'5%',height:'100%',backgroundColor:'orange',borderWidth:1,borderColor:'#fff',borderRadius:100}}/>
                </View>
                { this.state.dataFetched===0?<View style={{marginHorizontal:'50%',marginVertical:'50%',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size='large' color='red'/>
                  </View>:<View>


             <Text style={{fontSize:20,marginVertical:20,marginHorizontal:30,fontWeight:'bold',fontFamily:'arial'}}>{this.state.heading}</Text>

            <View>
                {
                  this.state.language.map((item,index)=>{
                      return(
                         <View style={style.mainlanguageScreen} key={index} >
                              {
                                this.state.intialLanguage===index?
                               <View style={style.languageBox}>

                                  <TouchableOpacity style={style.languageBoxInside}  onPress={()=>{this.props.languageSelectedIndexChanger(index), this.setState({intialLanguage:index}),this.urlFinder(index)}} >
                                        <View style={style.buttonOuter}>
                                        <View style={style.buttonInner}/>
                                        </View>
                                        <Text style={style.languageText}>{item.language_name}</Text>
                                 </TouchableOpacity>
                               </View>:
                              <View style={style.languageBox}>

                                  <TouchableOpacity style={style.languageBoxInside1}   onPress={()=>{this.props.languageSelectedIndexChanger(index), this.setState({intialLanguage:index}),this.urlFinder(index)}} >
                                      <View style={style.buttonOuter}/>
                                       <Text style={style.languageText}>{item.language_name}</Text>
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
                             </View>
                            }
                        </View>)

                    })}
          </View>
          <Text>{this.props.location_redux}</Text>
          <Text>{this.props.languageSelectedIndex}</Text>
                    </View>
                } 
          <View style={style.buttonPosition}>

                  <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SelectLocation')}>
                    <View style={style.buttonStyle} >
                    <Text style={style.styleOfNext}>{this.state.next}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

          </View>

      </View>

      );
    }
  }


  function mapStateToProps(state){

    return{
      languageSelectedIndex:state.languageSelectedIndex,
      location_redux:state.location

    }
    }
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
        return{
            languageSelectedIndexChanger:(key)=>dispatch({type:'LANG_INDEX-CHANGER',key})
        }
    }
  export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(chooseLanguageScreen)


  const style=StyleSheet.create({
    languageBox:{
      width:210,
      backgroundColor:'#fff',
      borderColor:'black',
      marginBottom:25,

    },
    mainlanguageScreen:{
      alignItems: 'center', 
      justifyContent: 'center',


    },
    languageBoxInside:{
      backgroundColor:'#f7931e',
      flexDirection:'row',
      alignItems:'center',
      paddingLeft:10
        },
      languageBoxInside1:{
         flexDirection:'row',
        alignItems:'center',
        paddingLeft:10
        },

    languageText:{
      color:'black',
      padding:10,
      fontSize:15


    },
      imageStyle:{
        width:25,
        height:25,
      },
      buttonStyle:{
        width:280,
        height:45,
        marginHorizontal:15,
        backgroundColor:'#862a2a',
        padding:10,
        alignItems:'center',
        borderRadius:5, 

      },
      buttonPosition:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'flex-end',
        marginBottom:10,

          },

      styleOfNext:{
        fontSize:20,
       color:'#fff'
      },
      newStyle:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'#eee',
        alignItems:'center'

      },
      buttonOuter:{
        width:25,
        height:25,
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius:100,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'#eee'
      },
      buttonInner:{
        width:12,
        height:12,
        backgroundColor:'orange',
        borderRadius:100
      }

    })
```

**selecting Location screen**:

```
import {Header,Left,Right,Body,Title}from 'native-base';
import React,{Component}from 'react';
import { View, Text,StyleSheet,Image,TouchableWithoutFeedback,Picker,ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import uncheck from '../assets/uncheck.png';
import checked from '../assets/checkedRadioButton.png';
import goBack from '../assets/goBack.png';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';


class chooseLocationScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

      return {
        header:null
      };
    };


    state={
      location:[],
      next:'',
      heading:'',
      intialLocation:0,
      uncheckRadioImage:uncheck,
      checkedRadioButton:checked,
      goBack:goBack,
      dataFetched:0
    }




    componentWillMount(){

      this.urlFinder(this.props.languageSelectedIndex)
      console.warn('mounted')
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
      console.warn('im DU location')
      if(this.props.languageSelectedIndex!==prevProps.languageSelectedIndex)
        {
          this.urlFinder(this.props.languageSelectedIndex)
        }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps,nextState){
      console.warn('im WU location')
      if(this.props.languageSelectedIndex!==nextProps.languageSelectedIndex)
      {
        this.urlFinder(this.props.languageSelectedIndex)
      }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(){
      this.urlFinder(this.props.languageSelectedIndex)
    }

    urlFinder(value){
      this.setState({dataFetched:0})
        checkedValue=value
      if(checkedValue==0){
        return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

          this.setState({
            heading:responseJson.heading,
            next: responseJson.next,
            location:responseJson.place_name,
            dataFetched:1
          });


        })
        .catch((error) =>{
          console.error(error);
        });
      }
     else if(checkedValue==1){
        return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

          this.setState({
            heading:responseJson.heading,
            next: responseJson.next,
            location:responseJson.place_name,
            dataFetched:1
          });

        })
        .catch((error) =>{
          console.error(error);
        });
      }
      else if(checkedValue==2){
        return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

          this.setState({
            heading:responseJson.heading,
            next: responseJson.next,
            location:responseJson.place_name,
            dataFetched:1
          });

        })
        .catch((error) =>{
          console.error(error);
        });
      }
    }


    render() {
      return (
        <View style={style.newStyle}>
        <Header style={{ backgroundColor:'#862a2a',width:'100%',
        height:80,}}>

          <Left>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}>
                 <Image style={style.imageStyle} source={this.state.goBack}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </Left>
          <Body style={{alignItems:'center',marginHorizontal:100}}>
              <Title style={{width:200}}>WECLEAN4YOU</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right style={{width:50,height:50}}>
                <Picker
                   selectedValue={this.state.pickerValue}
                   style={{height: 50, width: 60,color:'#fff'}}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>{ this.setState({pickerValue:itemValue}),this.props.languageSelectedIndexChanger(itemValue),this.urlFinder(itemValue)}}
                            >
                    <Picker.Item label="En" value='0' />
                    <Picker.Item label="Fr" value='1' />
                    <Picker.Item label="Ne" value='2' />
                 </Picker>

          </Right>

        </Header>

        <View style={{width:'100%',height:'3%',backgroundColor:'#af4141',flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <View style={{width:'12%',height:'100%',backgroundColor:'orange'}}/> 
                <View style={{marginLeft:-5,width:'5%',height:'100%',backgroundColor:'orange',borderWidth:1,borderColor:'#fff',borderRadius:100}}/>
                </View>


                { this.state.dataFetched===0?<View style={{marginHorizontal:'50%',marginVertical:'50%',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size='large' color='red'/>
                  </View>:<View>
        <Text style={{fontSize:20,marginVertical:20,marginHorizontal:30,fontWeight:'bold',fontFamily:'arial'}}>{this.state.heading}</Text>
          <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
          {this.state.location.map((item,index)=>{
            return(
              <View style={style.mainlanguageScreen} key={index}>
               {
                this.state.intialLocation===index?
                  <View style={style.languageBox}>
                      <TouchableOpacity style={style.languageBoxInside} onPress={()=>{this.setState({intialLocation:index}),this.props.locationChange(index)}} >
                         <View style={style.buttonOuter}>
                          <View style={style.buttonInner}/>
                         </View>
                         <Text style={style.languageText}>{item.location_name}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>:
                  <View style={style.languageBox}>
                     <TouchableOpacity style={style.languageBoxInside1} onPress={()=>{this.setState({intialLocation:index}),this.props.locationChange(index)}}>
                     <View style={style.buttonOuter}/>
                        <Text style={style.languageText}>{item.location_name}</Text>
                     </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                }

            </View>)

          })}
          </View>
          <Text>{this.props.location_redux}</Text>
                <Text>{this.props.languageSelectedIndex}</Text>
          </View>
                }
          <View style={style.buttonPosition}>

                <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DwellmingScreen')}>
                   <View style={style.buttonStyle}>
                     <Text style={style.styleOfNext}>{this.state.next}</Text>
                  </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
  function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
      languageSelectedIndex:state.languageSelectedIndex,
      location_redux:state.location,
    }
    }
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
        return{
            languageSelectedIndexChanger:(key)=>dispatch({type:'LANG_INDEX-CHANGER',key}),
            locationChange:(location)=>dispatch({type:'LOCATION_CHANGER',location})
        }
    }
  export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(chooseLocationScreen)
  const style=StyleSheet.create({
    languageBox:{
      width:210,
      backgroundColor:'#fff',
      borderColor:'black',
      marginBottom:25,

    },
    mainlanguageScreen:{
      alignItems: 'center', 
      justifyContent: 'center',


    },
    languageBoxInside:{
      backgroundColor:'#f7931e',
      flexDirection:'row',
      alignItems:'center',
      paddingLeft:10
        },
      languageBoxInside1:{
         flexDirection:'row',
        alignItems:'center',
        paddingLeft:10
        },

    languageText:{
      color:'black',
      padding:10,
      fontSize:15


    },
      imageStyle:{
        width:25,
        height:25,
      },
      buttonStyle:{
        width:280,
        height:45,
        marginHorizontal:15,
        backgroundColor:'#862a2a',
        padding:10,
        alignItems:'center',
        borderRadius:5, 

      },
      buttonPosition:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'flex-end',
        marginBottom:10,

          },

      styleOfNext:{
        fontSize:20,
       color:'#fff'
      },
      newStyle:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'#eee',
        alignItems:'center'

      },
      buttonOuter:{
        width:25,
        height:25,
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius:100,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'#eee'
      },
      buttonInner:{
        width:12,
        height:12,
        backgroundColor:'orange',
        borderRadius:100
      }

    })
```

Still I can't find the solution for that, please, give some idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss to return the rest of your state

```
const reducer = (state =initialState , action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'LANG_INDEX-CHANGER':
        return {
          ...state,
          languageSelectedIndex:action.key
        }

      case 'LOCATION_CHANGER':
        return{
          ...state,
          location:action.location
        }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```